# java best way to transfer images

Tags: java, file, out-of-memory

I have a application that reads a PDF, transform the content to collection of TIF files, and send them to Glass Fish Server for saving.

Usually there are 1-5 pages and it works nice, but when I got a input file with 100+ pages...
it throws error on the transfer.

```
 Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2786)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:94)
```

Putting more resources is not a good option in my case, so I m looking for a way to optimize it somehow.
I store the data in:

```
HashMap<TifProfile, List<byte[]>
```

Is there a better way to store  or  send them ?

**EDIT** 
I did some tests and the final collections for PDF with 80 pages
has size over 280mb  (240 tiffs with different settings inside)

Comment: Without more information there is little we can do.

Comment: How big (in size of MBs) is that 100+ long PDF?

Comment: Sounds like a memory related issue to me.

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't give us much to go on, but it seems clear to me that storing 100+ high resolution TIFF-encoded images in memory will very quickly exhaust any resources you have available.

It might be better to load it into the database in batches, e.g. just handle 5 pages at a time.

Alternatively depending on your JDBC driver, you might be able to stream the image data into a JDBC BLOB so you wont have to cache it in memory. Heres some food for thought...

http://artofsystems.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/mysql-postgresql-and-blob-streaming.html